# Two y-axis in Matlab: Setting different ranges and color

Tags: matlab

I am a noob when it comes to Matlab and I would appreciate any help! I need to create a figure with two y axis, and in order to satisfy my tutors I have to use specific ranges for them, and also to make it "more appealing" use colours that make some sense.

So I have two questions:

First, how can I set different ranges for the two y axis? I know I can use ylim([]} easily for 1 y axis but that doesn't seem to work.

Secondly, how can I easily change the color and format of one plot?(preferably they are the same as the color of the y axis they are assigned to,  but Matlab automatically chooses them weirdly) Sadly sth like this won't work:

```
plot(x,y,'r','-','LineWidth',2.0);
```

It would be perfect if the first and second plot have the same format so  '-' and the third and fourth another e.g. '--' but the plots Colors stay the same as their respective axis.

This is my current figure:
[image: First Version]

The following is my code

```
clc

A=dlmread('bipsim2_220.txt');
B=dlmread('bipsim2_680.txt');

x=A(:,1);
y=A(:,3);
plot(x,y,'LineWidth',2.0);
yyaxis left

hold on

x2=A(:,1);
y2=A(:,2);
plot(x2,y2,'LineWidth',2.0);
yyaxis right

hold on

x3=B(:,1);
y3=B(:,3);
plot(x3,y3,'LineWidth',2.0);
yyaxis left

hold on

x4=B(:,1);
y4=B(:,2);
plot(x4,y4,'LineWidth',2.0);
yyaxis right

yyaxis left
ylabel('Verstärkung (dB)')

yyaxis right
ylabel('Phase (deg)')

ylabel('Freq (Hz)')

set(gca,'Xscale','log')

set(gca,'fontsize',18)

hold off

grid minor
legend('R48/220 Ω: Phase [deg]','R48/220 Ω: Gain [dB]','R51/680 Ω: Phase [deg]','R51/680 Ω: Gain [dB]')
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

- You can specify colors using RGB tuple with the `color` keyword agrument
- You can specify linewidth using the `linewidth` keyword argument
- You can specify styles as a positional argument after the data.
- You can easily get X with logscale using `semilogx`
- `twinx` will create a secondary Y-axis on with the labels on the right sharing the same X-axis.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
freq = np.logspace(0, 5) # your frequency grid
# I made up a transfer function
H = lambda s: (s**2 - 1e2*s + 1e2) / (s - 1e3)**2 
g = H(2j * np.pi * freq); # evaluate the transfer function at the frequency grid
# plot
plt.semilogx(freq, 20 * np.log10(abs(g)), '--k', linewidth=2)
plt.ylabel('Gain [dB]')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]');
plt.grid()
plt.twinx()
plt.semilogx(freq, 180 * np.angle(g) / np.pi, '-', linewidth=2, color=[0.8, 0.5, 0.3])
plt.ylabel('Phase [degrees]')
```

[image: how it looks]

you can also specify predefined colors e.g `k` for black.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

- You only need to call `hold on` once on the figure. Everything plotted after the first `hold on` will keep in the plot until you clear it with `clf`.
- You can specify color and line style for each of your plots individually in its respective call to `plot(...)`
- You need to set `yyaxis left` or `yyaxis right` **before** the thing you want to appear on that axis. This Matlab "from now on, we're now going to use the left/right axis"
- On the same note, once you've set the approriate axis, you can manipulate its color and range.

In your code (untested because I don't have your input text files):

```
A=dlmread('bipsim2_220.txt');
B=dlmread('bipsim2_680.txt');

% resorted to have data and plotting separate (no need to do this, just easier to read the plotting part)
x1=A(:,1);
y1=A(:,3);
x2=A(:,1);
y2=A(:,2);
x3=B(:,1);
y3=B(:,3);
x4=B(:,1);
y4=B(:,2);

% set colors as a variables to change them easier
colorLeft = 'r'; % red
colorRight = 'k'; % black

% let's just open a clean figure
clf;

% set hold to on
hold on;

%% do stuff for the left y axis (gain)
yyaxis left;

% plot data with respective color and line style
plot(x1,y1,'LineWidth',2.0, 'Color', colorLeft, 'LineStyle', '-');
plot(x3,y3,'LineWidth',2.0, 'Color', colorLeft, 'LineStyle', '--');
% axis formating
ylabel('Verstärkung (dB)');
ylim([-200, 50]); % chose lower and upper limit for left y-axis 
ax = gca; % all the formating of the axis is stored in an axis object which we can manipulate
ax.YColor = colorLeft; % set color of current (i.e. left) y-axis

%% now we move to do stuff for the right y axis (phase)
yyaxis right;

% plot data with respective color and line style
plot(x2,y2,'LineWidth',2.0, 'Color', colorRight, 'LineStyle', '-');
plot(x4,y4,'LineWidth',2.0, 'Color', colorRight, 'LineStyle', '--');
% axis formating
ylabel('Phase (deg)');
ylim([-180, 0]); % chose lower and upper limit for right y-axis 
ax.YColor = colorRight; % set color of current (i.e. right) y-axis

%% finally, set all the format stuff not related to a particular y-axis
xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
ax.XScale = 'log';
ax.FontSize = 18;
grid minor

% hold off % no need to turn hold off, its only affecting the current figure anyway

%make sure that the order of legend entries fits the order in which you plot the curves
legend('R48/220 Ω: Gain [dB]','R51/680 Ω: Gain [dB]', 'R48/220 Ω: Phase [deg]','R51/680 Ω: Phase [deg]');
```